# Select que recupere registros con distinto valor

Tags: php, joomla3

Tengo una tabla A con 3 columnas: SubmissionId, FieldName y FieldValue.

**1) SubmissionId** guarda el ID de la submission.

**2) FieldName y FieldValue** guardan respectivamente el nombre del campo de un formulario y su valor.

Tengo un formulario con 3 campos: Nombre, email y estatus. Si se han hecho 4 submissions, en total habrá 12 registros: 3 por cada submission.

¿Cómo recupero los 3 registros de una submission si el campo estatus de esa submission es igual a la cadena "abierto"?

¿Se puede? Empiezo con esto, pero evidentemente sólo recupera el registro que contiene el campo "estatus". Necesito los otros 2 campos.

```
->where($db->quoteName('b.FieldName') . ' = \'estatus\' AND ' . $db->quoteName('b.FieldValue') . ' = \'abierto\'' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría con una subquery que encuentre primero el submissionId de la 'submission' con los dos valores que tengo y luego simplemente obtengo las líneas que tienen ese submissionId:

```
$tableName = 'submissions';

$subQuery = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select($db->qn('b.SubmissionId'))
    ->from($db->qn($tableName))
    ->where($db->qn('b.FieldName') . " = 'estatus' AND " . $db->qn('b.FieldValue') . " = 'abierto'" );

$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->select('*')
    ->from($db->qn($tableName))
    ->where($db->qn('b.SubmissionId') . " = (" . $subQuery . "));

$db->setQuery($query);
```